# How do you shut off this water softener bypass valve?

Tags: valve

[image]

Post title says it all.  I am stumped.  It's the knobs on the left and the right side in the photo.  However, I am unable to turn them.  I have tried to pry the red clips up and then turn, but that doesn't work.  I haven't been able to remove the red clips, either.

Does anyone here know how to operate one of these valves?  They are unlike any I have seen online.

Comment: Pulling *out* on the knobs might free them to turn, but looking at it I would just assume they should turn as it. I would advise you to not try to remove the orange clips. Since they are on the connections as well as on the valves I would suspect that they are holding the parts of the valves in place against water pressure. Call the water softener service.

Comment: Generally these knobs pull out - hold them above the red clip and pull out and then turn while pulling out. The other option is to push in and turn - but unlikely ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you found an answer elsewhere, but I found a Youtube video addressing this issue.  The trick is that there are holes in the knobs where you can insert a screwdriver to give you more torque.  No need to pull out the knob or remove the clips.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKVvOCaGQJc

Comment: Can you describe the video to us, in case the link breaks or the likes?

Comment: from the look of the video you probably could have just turned them by hand..sticking something in the hole just gives leverage.